# Unable to extract image src with bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to scrape this website product image src's using BeautifulSoup. The problem is that when I use the image class to select the src I get the error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

This is what I have:

```
images = soup.find_all('img', {'class': 'css-1rovmyu e65zztl0'})['src'] # gives error ^
```

Also when I do:

```
images = soup.find_all('img')

for image in images: 
   print(image['src'])
```

It returns all the image src's and works fine. I was reading another problem similar to fine and it said the fact that the image is nested may be the problem but it didnt work. This is the structure:

```
<picture class="css-yq9732">
    <img class="css-1rovmyu e65zztl0" src="image src">
</picture>
```

Comment: It's because `find_all` is returning a list, but you're using a key to try to access it. Just doing `soup.find_all('img', {'class': 'css-1rovmyu e65zztl0'})[0]['src']` would work to get the first element

Comment: although `select_one` or something similar would probably work better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`images` is a `list`, you have to access the index of the list and extract the value.
For example:

```
images = soup.find_all('img', {'class': 'css-1rovmyu e65zztl0'})

print(images[0]["src"])
```

Or to only get the first tag, use `find()` instead of `find_all()`